# Guava Function<> with void return value?

Tags: c#, java, functional-programming, guava

Does Googe Guava for Java have a Function inner class with a void return value, like C#'s `action`? I'm tired of making a bunch of `Function<Float, Integer>` with meaningless return values.

Answer (score 11):

You could use a `Function<Float, Void>` and have it return `null` to make your intentions more clear. Or you could make your own abstract class that implements `Function<T, Void>` too if you want.

But no, Guava doesn't have anything like that... it also doesn't have any methods designed to use something like that, such as a `forEach` type method. If you're using Guava's methods that use `Function`s with a `Function<Float, Void>` or some such... I wouldn't really recommend that, since the methods aren't designed for that (even if you *can* with some of them).  If you're using your own methods for this, I'd say just make your own interface like `Callback<T>`.

Comment: Isn't it something like a closure ?

Comment: @Sylvain: Any anonymous inner class declared in a method is a closure that closes over fields in the enclosing class and final variables in the method it's declared in. Non-static inner classes declared elsewhere also close over the fields of their containing class.

Comment: Ok, thx for the explanation, so if I understand well, this case is just an example of closure. I'm right ?

Comment: @Sylvain: Right. Closure is a pretty broad term. A lot of people also use "closure" when they mean "lambda expression".

Answer (score 1):

To me this seems contradictory; you want to use a Function (which computes a value based on input value), but do not want to return a value (which functions normally do; that's how they're supposed to communicate the return value to caller).

So why not just do

```
    for (Value v : values) {
        doYourThing(v);
    }
```

It's more compact than creating a Function and performs better, too. In fact, if I understood your usage correctly, using Function would provide no benefits but would just add quite a bit of boilerplate code.